# Cheap RAID controller for ESXi

Tags: raid-controller

I'm planning to create a small homelab with ESXi 6.7U3:

- CPU: I3 9100
- Motherboard: Gigabyte B360N
- RAM: 16GB DDR4
- VM storage: 2 SATA SSD
- Boot ESXi from 16 GB USB key

Is there any ESXi 6.7 compatible RAID controller under 100$ to put the 2 SATA SSDs in RAID1? I've just checked the VMWare compatibility page, but all the options listed seem to be a lot more expensive than my small budget.

Please forgive my english and thanks in advance for your help.